# why this python function has a strange output?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new in python, so I do not understand function well

```
  def extendList(val,list=[]):
        list.append(val)
        return list
    list1 = extendList(10)
    list2 =  extendList(123,["a","b","c"])
    list3 = extendList('a')
    print "list1 = %s"% list1
    print "list2 = %s" % list2
    print "list3 = %s" % list3
```

The result I expected is

```
list1 = [10]
list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 123]
list3 = ['a']
```

However,the actual result is

```
list1 = [10, 'a']
list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 123]
list3 = [10, 'a']
```

Why is it happening ?

Comment: list1 and list3 actually refer to the same list

Comment: Take a look at this: https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/mutable_default_value_as_argument.html

Comment: `list` is a built-in type and function in Python. Please consider naming your objects differently (e.g. `list1`, like you do below).